# Run jQuery Counter with value from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have jQuery counter which move numbers from one fixed number to other fixed number. But I want to create the Counter which end at number which come from MySQL database.

Counter Function Code:

Now It starts value from 99950 and end value is 100000 but I want to change end value. It should be the value which I fetch from mysql.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function($) {
    $.fn.countTo = function(options) {
        // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

        // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
        var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
            increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

        return $(this).each(function() {
            var _this = this,
                loopCount = 0,
                value = options.from,
                interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

            function updateTimer() {
                value += increment;
                loopCount++;
                $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));

                if (typeof(options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                    options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
                }

                if (loopCount >= loops) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    value = options.to;

                    if (typeof(options.onComplete) == 'function') {
                        options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
        from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
        to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
        speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
        refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
        decimals: 0,  // the number of decimal places to show
        onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
        onComplete: null,  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
    };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function($) {
        $('.timer').countTo({
            from: 99950,
            to: 100000,
            speed: 2000,
            refreshInterval: 50,
            onComplete: function(value) {
                console.debug(this);
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<h2><span class="timer" style="color:#F44336;font-weight:700; font-size:20px;"></span></h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a server side language for getting data extracted from mysql. Say for instance, if you are using PHP as your server side language, in that case you can simply put :

```
<?php 
 mysql_connect('host','username','password') or die();
 mysql_select_db('your_database_name') or die();
 $query='SELECT `min_count`, `max_count` FROM 'your_table_name`;
 $row=mysql_query($query);
 while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($row)){
  $from=$rs[0];
  $to=$rs[1];
 }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

(function($) {
    $.fn.countTo = function(options) {
        // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

        // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
        var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
            increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

        return $(this).each(function() {
            var _this = this,
                loopCount = 0,
                value = options.from,
                interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

            function updateTimer() {
                value += increment;
                loopCount++;
                $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));

                if (typeof(options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                    options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
                }

                if (loopCount >= loops) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    value = options.to;

                    if (typeof(options.onComplete) == 'function') {
                        options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
        from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
        to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
        speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
        refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
        decimals: 0,  // the number of decimal places to show
        onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
        onComplete: null,  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
    };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function($) {
        $('.timer').countTo({
            from: <?php echo "$from"; ?>,
            to: <?php echo "$to"; ?>,
            speed: 2000,
            refreshInterval: 50,
            onComplete: function(value) {
                console.debug(this);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you plz tell one thing how we can add comma in to: 1,000,00.

Comment: Can you plz tell one thing how we can add comma in to: 1,000,00

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, you want to get an sql query to the counter? 
You could use AJAX for that, make a php file with an sql query and call it from the script using Ajax.

Comment: Yes exactly.. Can you pls help me out how it can be done.

Comment: $.ajax({       url: ,// PHP File containing Query       type: 'post',       success: function(data, status) {         // Here handle the output. The query  //result. You can use PHP echo.        },       error: function(xhr, desc, err) {         // Here handle the errors       }     }); // end ajax call   });

Comment: Use the script above.. and put in the URL you php script. Containing the query. Inside the PHP script. Echo the data. Then in your Javascript in the success, put the result in a variable for use.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'endpoint to php script',
    success: function(data) { 
        $('.timer').countTo({
            from: data.startFrom,
            to: data.endOn,
            speed: 2000,
            refreshInterval: 50,
            onComplete: function(value) {
                console.debug(this);
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
//I assume you know how connect to your database and get data
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

$result = array(
        'startFrom' => 1000,
        'endOn' => 9000
    ); 

echo json_encode($result);
```

I thnik it's clear and explain this code is not needed